# How to remove the link?

Tags: jquery

I need to show some text when a user clicks a link, and then remove the link after it has been clicked.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/HCAfz/2/

How do I remove the link that was clicked from the page and keep the behavior above, with the hidden div being shown?

Comment: The you want to remove the `a` tag on click? Also the contents??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To completely remove the link do:

```
$('a.yourLink').click(function(event) {
    $(this).next('.hiddenDiv').show();
    window.open(this.href, '_blank');
    $(this).remove();

    return false;
});
```

To hide the link do:

```
$('a.yourLink').click(function(event) {
    $(this).next('.hiddenDiv').show();
    window.open(this.href, '_blank');
    $(this).hide();

    return false;
});
```

Note that I do `return false;` in stead of `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopPropagation();` since it is the same

Answer (score 1):

like this you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/HCAfz/4/

EDIT:

This is much better per Stefan's suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/HCAfz/6/

Comment: `.hide()` would make more sense here, or `.remove`

Answer (score 1):

You need to explain yourself better, but for the most simplest case add this line:

```
$(this).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this

```
$('a.yourLink').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide().next('.hiddenDiv').show();
        window.open(this.href, '_blank');
 });
```